# При попытке удалить один объект класса - удаляются все

Tags: python, delete

Почему-то метод `__del__` в классе `Personal_Data` удаляет все объекты, вместо одного. С чем это может быть связано и как это исправить?

```
class Personal_Data:
    total_people = 0 # Количество людей в телефонной книге
    def __init__(self, name, surname, phone_number):
        # Метод инициализации пользователя
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        Personal_Data.total_people += 1

    def __del__(self):
        print("Удален пользоваетль: {0}".format(self.name))
         # Удаление пользователя
        Personal_Data.total_people -= 1
        # Выводится оставшееся количество людей в телефоной книге
        print("Количество пользователей: {0}".format(Personal_Data.total_people))

    def introduce(self):
        print("Имя: {0}, Фамилия: {1}, Номер телефона {2}".format(self.name, self.surname, self.phone_number))

# Объекты класса
Vasiliy = Personal_Data('Vasiliy', 'Valakas', '88005553535')
Ivan = Personal_Data('Ivan', 'Ivanov', '88005553535')

# Объекты заносятся в список для дальнейших манипуляций с ними
members = [Vasiliy, Ivan]

for member in members:
    if member.name != member.name.lower():
        member.name = member.name.lower() # Если в строке есть символы с верхним регистром, то они переводятся в нижний 

print("Что можно сделать: Посмотреть контакты (наберите 'контакты'), Добавить новый контакт ('добавить'), Удалить контакт ('удалить')")
# Пользователь выбирает какое действие совершить
void = input("Что будем делать --> ")

if void != void.lower():
    void = void.lower() # Если в строке есть символы с верхним регистром, то они переводятся в нижний 

if void == 'контакты':
    for member in members:
        # Все пользователи заносятся в словарь, где ключом является имя пользователя
        new_dict = {
            member.name: member.phone_number
        }
        print(new_dict)

elif void == 'удалить':
    # Программа спрашивает какого пользователя удалить
    delete_who = input("Какого пользователя вы хотите удалить? --> ")
    if delete_who != delete_who.lower():
        delete_who = delete_who.lower() # Если в строке есть символы с верхним регистром, то они переводятся в нижний 
    # Программа удаляет пользователя
    del delete_who
else:
    print("Действие не найдено!")
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что у вас вообще что-то удаляется? Судя по коду, вы пытаетесь удалить введенную строку.

Comment: Даже если удалить код, который "удаляет" объект, введённый в input, то все объекты всё равно удаляются, несмотря ни на что.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объекты удаляются, потому, что скрипт завершился и удаляется вообще всё, что относится к этому скрипту.

Видимо, вам стоит завернуть в бесконечный цикл всю ту часть кода, которая отвечате за взаимодействие с пользователем, чтобы программа не завершалась после первой же выполненной команды.

У вас есть проблемы и в других местах:

```
# Все пользователи заносятся в словарь, где ключом является имя пользователя
new_dict = {
    member.name: member.phone_number
}
print(new_dict)
```

Нет, не все пользователи заносятся в словарь. У вас словарь пересоздаётся заново на каждой итерации. Так что в нём в итоге останется только последний объект.

Ну и про то, что del delete_who удаляет только строку с именем, но не удаляет объект, вам уже написали в комментариях.